# Finding consecutive days in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
  ColA  ColB

0   A    1/2/2020 
1   A    1/3/2020       
2   A    1/4/2020
3   A    1/10/2020 
4   B    1/3/2020
5   B    1/19/2020
6   C    1/2/2020
7   C    1/7/2020 
8   D    1/8/2020
```

Now I want to find out the name of the series in `colA` which has three consecutive days in `colB`.

Output:

the answer would be `A` since it has `1/2/2020`, `1/3/2020` and `1/4/2020` in `colB`.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach would be like this:

```
# 1. To make sure the dates are sorted
df = df.sort_values(["ColA", "ColB"])

# 2. Standardize the dates by offseting them
df["ColB_std"] = df["ColB"] - pd.to_timedelta(range(df.shape[0]), 'day')

# 3. Counting each instance of ColA and standardized date
s = df.groupby(["ColA", "ColB_std"])["ColB_std"].count()

# 4. Getting elements from ColA that have at least 1 sequence of at least length 3
colA = s[ s >= 3 ].index.get_level_values(0).unique().values

# 5. Filtering the dataframe
df[ df["ColA"].isin(colA) ]
```

You want `ColA`s with 3 consecutive dates. Or you could think of it like you want `ColA`s where there's a sequence of `date`, `date + 1 day` and `date + 2 days`. By sorting the dataframe by ColA and ColB **(1)**, we know that in the case you want to check, `date + 1 day` will always follow `date`, and `date + 2 days` will be the following that one.

With this, you can standardize the dates by removing `n` days corresponding to their row. So, the sequence of `date`, `date + 1 day` and `date + 2 days`, becomes `date`, `date` and `date` **(2)**.

Now that we have the date column standardized, we just need to count how many elements each pair `('ColA', 'ColB_std')` exist **(3)**, get the elements from `ColA` that have counts of 3 or more **(4)**, and filter the dataframe **(5)**.

However, this doesn't support duplicated pairs of `('ColA', 'ColB')`, for that you'd need to do this first:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(["ColA", "ColB"])
```

Proceding to use this `df2` in steps 1, 2, 3 and 4, and in the end filtering the real `df` in step 5.

*Previously, I answered that you also could do it like this*:

```
# To make sure the dates are sorted
df = df.sort_values(["ColA", "ColB"])

# Calculating the difference between dates inside each group
s = df.groupby("ColA")["ColB"].diff().dt.days

# Filtering the dataframe
df[ ((s == 1) & (s.shift(1) == 1)).groupby(df["ColA"]).transform("any") ]
```

The idea is that in `s`, the difference is always between the previous date, and the current date. However, this doesn't make sure that there are 3 consecutive dates, just 2. By shifting the series by 1, you are make sure that the current different and the previous one are 1 [ `(s == 1) & (s.shift(1) == 1)` ].

After that, I just `groupby(df["ColA"])`, and check if any element inside the group is true with `transform("any")`.

Comment: I am getting this error-ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('<m8[ns]') and dtype('O')

Comment: Can you validate that when you print `df.dtypes`, `ColB` is of type `datetime64[ns]`? If this is the case, can you provide me an example of your error in a comment or in an online IDE like [repl.it](https://repl.it/) ?

Comment: Can you explain the 3rd step?

Comment: Here is a image, it might help besides the explanation in the answer: https://imgur.com/BefUOub