# Adding multiple columns in the isin function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code-

```
colA = s[ s >= 3 ].index.get_level_values(0).unique().values
df=df[df["CITY"].isin(colA) ]
```

I want to add multiple columns in the `df=df[df["CITY"].isin(colA) ]` command the columns are CITY, NUMBER and AREA.

Do i just add the conditions separately with & conditions or is there a better way?

link to question-[Finding consecutive days in the pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59965641/finding-consecutive-days-in-the-pandas-dataframe)

In this question, I want to add two more columns colA colB colC in the answer provided by @MkWTF

Comment: Can you add some data, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Agree with @jezrael, please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: [JFYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)